# AWS lambda function for auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-auto-scaling

I am creating a Disaster recovery solution in AWS. For second (fallback) region i want to have only 1 EC2 instance to minimise cost. In case of disaster i would like to know if it's possible to write a lambda function in the second region that increases the desired capacity of the auto Scaling group to some number.

To achieve this i can subscribe the function to the health check alarm SNS topic.

I would like to know if there is a API to autoscale a ec2 group from Lambda and what sort of roles/permissions is needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible.

In Boto3 you can use the [update_autoscaling_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.update_auto_scaling_group) function and specify the `MinSize`, `MaxSize` and `DesiredCapacity`. By doing this you would be able to adjust the values to match what you expect them to be at.

Alternatively you could have the minimum capacity as 1 and the maximum capacity as whatever it should be, if the alarms never trigger it would never scale. You could simply then call the [set_desired_capacity](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.set_desired_capacity) to set the number of instances to a specific count.

The permissions for these options are as follows:

- `autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity`
- `autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup`